# In WSO2 ESB, how to store cookies and use them later for authentication?

Tags: wso2-esb

I have a service that I am calling, which is returning back cookies with authentication info.  How do I store the cookies, and use them later?

This is not working for me.  I see the cookies being returned back, but I don't see it getting set.

```
<!-- LOGON CALL -->
<property xmlns:ns="http://org.apache.synapse/xsd" xmlns:ns3="http://org.apache.synapse/xsd" name="setCookieHeader" expression="$trp:cookie"></property>
<payloadFactory media-type="xml">
    <format><somexml></somexml></format>
</payloadFactory>
<call>
    <endpoint>
       <address uri="http://serviceurl.domain.com" format="pox"></address>
    </endpoint>
</call>
<log>
<property name="cookie" expression="get-property('setCookieHeader')"></property>
</log>
<!-- The Above Log statement prints correctly -->

<!-- Second Service CALL -->
<property xmlns:ns="http://org.apache.synapse/xsd" xmlns:ns3="http://org.apache.synapse/xsd" name="setCookieHeader" expression="$trp:cookie"></property>
<payloadFactory media-type="xml">
    <format><somexml></somexml></format>
</payloadFactory>
<call>
    <endpoint>
       <address uri="http://serviceurl.domain.com" format="pox"></address>
    </endpoint>
</call>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get cookies from the response :

```
<property name="setCookieHeader" expression="$trp:Set-Cookie" scope="default" type="STRING"/>
```

To set cookies for the next request :

```
<property name="Cookie" expression="$ctx:setCookieHeader" scope="transport"/> <!-- if setCookieHeader has been initialized before -->
```

Or

```
<property name="Cookie" expression="$trp:Set-Cookie" scope="transport"/>
```