# Set / store cookie on wso2 ESB

Tags: cookies, wso2, wso2-esb

I have endpoint from thirdparty that require us to authenticate.
The response from endpoint authenticate is a cookie session. 
I need to fetch the cookie response from this authentication endpoint, and then  to call another endpoint (e.g : search endpoint) with this cookie.

I'm trying without wso2 and no problem with it, and the problem is while using wso2 ESB.

I have successfuly request endpoint authentication via wso2 ESB and, the response is return success, 
Then i try to call another endpoint (e.g : search endpoint), the response is 403 forbidden (authenticate failed), that mean cookie is not send/set in search endpoint.

How can i fix this ?

I have try :
1. [WSO2 ESB Getting a cookie from transport header with multiple cookies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32990465/wso2-esb-getting-a-cookie-from-transport-header-with-multiple-cookies)
2. [In WSO2 ESB, how to store cookies and use them later for authentication?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27788670/in-wso2-esb-how-to-store-cookies-and-use-them-later-for-authentication)

Thanks a lot

Comment: It would be awesome if you could provide a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 0):

Have you set the cookie?As you haven't provided details of your code.

```
<property xmlns:ns="http://org.apache.synapse/xsd" name="Cookie" expression="$trp.Set-Cookie"></property>

<property name="Cookie" value="JSESSIONID=1" scope="transport"/>
```

If the response from first call is a cookie session then i would suggest that you can write the session in a registry file so that you can fetch the session whenever you want.